# wkhtmltopdf not working in Eclipse and/or Spyder

Tags: eclipse, python-2.7, pydev, wkhtmltopdf, spyder

Trying to export a webpage as pdf in Eclipse or Spyder, I can successfully run the following script in the Mac terminal:

```
import pdfkit
import wkhtmltopdf
pdfkit.from_url('http://google.com', 'out.pdf')
```

But, this script does not work in either Eclipse PyDev or Anaconda Spyder giving the following error:

IOError: No wkhtmltopdf executable found: ""
If this file exists please check that this process can read it. Otherwise please install wkhtmltopdf - https://github.com/JazzCore/python-pdfkit/wiki/Installing-wkhtmltopdf
ERROR: Module: xxxx could not be imported (file: /Users/MyMac/Documents/myproject/mwe.py).

Note that I am using Python 2.7 and it seems  **wkhtmltopdf** does not work properly in Python 3.*
Also, I have added **wkhtmltopdf**'s folder to PYTHONPATH.

Comment: Please provide the full, real error, not just a redacted excerpt as doing so omits information needed to diagnose it. Also, what's the name of your module? (maybe some name is conflicting?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add the `..\wkhtmltopdf\bin` to your PYTHONPATH.

In **Eclipse** go to *project -> properties -> PyDev-PYTHONPATH* and at the register *External Libraries* add your source folder (full path to `..\wkhtmltopdf\bin`).